# undefined control sequence using subsubsubsection

Tags: sectioning

When I do something like:

```
\subsubsubsection{Testing}
```

I get Undefined control sequence. It works find for `\subsubsection{Testing}`. How can I incorporate a 3rd level?

Comment: the next level is called `\paragraph` then `\subparagraph`

Comment: If I use this then my text start on the same line as the heading. How do I get it to start on a different line. Also, how do I number the heading?

Comment: @JacksonHart: `\paragraph` and `\subparagraph` are not designed to start a new line after the title in standard classes. If you want them numbered use `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}` in the preamble

Comment: @JacksonHart see the answers in the linked question, you can adjust the styling of the headings at all the levels.